# Java app for SSH connection

Tags: ssh, java-applet

I want to connect to my job computer. IT offers Java applet for SSH connection.

Problem - this Java MindTerm app really sucks. Can't copy, save etc.
What I want:

1. Is is possible to use another Java app (MindTerm is the default and their are no other options);

2. Is it possible to connect via my linux terminal?

Looking forward

Comment: From the terminal, just running `ssh <user>@<server>` should be enough. The server address should be in MindTerm's configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the server name (which should be somewhere in MindTerm's configuration), you can connect directly from your terminal using OpenSSH:

```
ssh <user>@<server>
```

From a Windows machine, you can use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).